# Multiple Inner Joins with MS Access producing multiple results.. need grouping and totalling

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have spent a good 20 minutes searching for similar questions answered but most are not specified for MS Access Databases.

Unfortunately my experience of SQL is very limited so I would appreciate your input on this.

You can download the Access Database from this link here to see what I am trying to accomplish [TestDB.zip](http://www.meista.co.uk/TestDB.zip).

This image shows a very basic table setup as an example in MS Access 2003 of what I wish to achieve:
[image]

Basically I would like to run an SQL query which will display the Orders with all the information held in the related tables.

Obviously, an SQL query such as the one below will display multiple rows with repeated information which is not what I want.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderTitle, Materials.Material, Materials.MaterialCost,
       Labour.HoursTaken, Invoices.InvoiceAmount
  FROM ((Orders INNER JOIN Labour ON Orders.OrderID = Labour.OrderID)
                INNER JOIN Materials ON Orders.OrderID = Materials.OrderID)
 INNER JOIN Invoices ON Orders.OrderID = Invoices.OrderID;
```

Results:
[image]

Basically, I would like a query which will SUM up each of the materials, hours and invoices for each order. Something I have produced in this spreadsheet as desired can be seen here:
[image]

Obviously, this SQL doesn't work because the figures are all over the place due to the multiple rows due to the INNER JOINS.

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderTitle, Sum(Materials.MaterialCost) AS SumOfMaterialCost,
       Sum(Labour.HoursTaken) AS SumOfHoursTaken, 
       Sum(Invoices.InvoiceAmount) AS SumOfInvoiceAmount
  FROM ((Orders INNER JOIN Labour ON Orders.OrderID = Labour.OrderID) 
                INNER JOIN Materials ON Orders.OrderID = Materials.OrderID) 
 INNER JOIN Invoices ON Orders.OrderID = Invoices.OrderID
 GROUP BY Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderTitle;
```

Results here:
[image]

I have looked at multiple SELECT statements but I don't think that these are supported in MS Access

Comment: It would be easier/preferable to post the table structures, sample data and query results here instead of in a .zip file stored elsewhere. If the .zip file link ever fails, then this info will be missing making this question difficult to understand.

Comment: Not only that, but you previously posted this question and then deleted it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12819833/multiple-inner-joins-with-ms-access-producing-multiple-results-need-grouping) (10k+ only). If you do not get an answer to a question, consider revising it not re-posting a new one.

Comment: I posted the zip file containing the example  Access DB and table structure with this new submission. I deleted the old post and resubmitted to hopefully not confuse people with two posts.

Comment: You should post that data here in the question, not in a .zip file stored on another website.  If that website is unavailable, then this data is gone.

Comment: Ah OK - then I apologise and definitely did not intend to mislead anyone. The meista website is my own - have you had the chance to look at it? I tried to post images, structure on this website but as a new member it restricted me posting images.

Comment: This is often referred to as a "chasm trap". As is shown in the answers already given, you need to aggregate from the leaf tables before joining to the master table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subqueries will get you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT O.OrderID, O.OrderTitle, 
   (SELECT Sum(M.MaterialCost) FROM Materials AS M
    WHERE M.OrderID=O.OrderID) AS SumOfMaterialCost,
   (SELECT Sum(L.HoursTaken) FROM Labour AS L
    WHERE L.OrderID=O.OrderID) AS SumOfHoursTaken, 
   (SELECT Sum(I.InvoiceAmount) FROM Invoices AS I
    WHERE I.OrderID=O.OrderID)  AS SumOfInvoiceAmount
FROM Orders AS O
```

See [Subquery Basics](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html) and [Surviving Subqueries](http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-02.html) for some more good info.

Comment: Ohhhh this is almost there.... I put the SQL code in, hit run and I am asked to enter a Parameter Value. If I remove the part from the top line I get the totaling which works GREAT  

  `SELECT
   (SELECT Sum(M.MaterialCost) FROM Materials AS M
    WHERE M.OrderID=O.OrderID) AS SumOfMaterialCost,
   (SELECT Sum(L.HoursTaken) FROM Labour AS L
    WHERE L.OrderID=O.OrderID) AS SumOfHoursTaken, 
   (SELECT Sum(I.InvoiceAmount) FROM Invoices AS I
    WHERE I.OrderID=O.OrderID)  AS SumOfInvoiceAmount
FROM Orders AS O`  

  ...but I still need at least the Order No to reference from.

Comment: It's OK. I fixed it by replacing the  `SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.OrderTitle`  to  `SELECT O.OrderID, O.OrderTitle. Thank you so much for your help. It is massively appreciated!

Comment: Sorry about that.  I updated my answer accordingly for future users.